# How to update a jira issue summary though the rest api using restsharp

Tags: c#-4.0, restsharp, jira-rest-java-api

I have been playing around with the jira rest api to eventually replace my soap implementation in a c# app using the 4.0 .net framework. I am also using restsharp.

While i had no problem getting an issue or searching for an issue with the rest api, i have been pulling my hairs with updating a jira issue. These are my execute methods, they work fine to do get or search jira issues. Usual error message i get when i call SetJiraIssue is the following {"errorMessages":["one of 'fields' or 'update' required"],"errors":{}}.

If i pass a simple JSOn string exeample(string jSonContent = @"{""Fields"":{""summary"":"" testing summary update""}}") to the body of the request, then it complains that there is no constructor for it.

Anybody out there as an idea of what i am doing wrong? Comments and suggestion are more then welcome

```
  private string Execute(RestRequest request)
    {
        var client = new RestClient(_jiraUrl);

        client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator(_accountId, _password);
        request.AddParameter("AccountSid", _accountId, ParameterType.UrlSegment);
        var response = client.Execute(request);

        if (response.ErrorException != null)
        {
            const string message = "Error retrieving response.  Check inner details for more info.";
            var jiraManagerException = new ApplicationException(message, response.ErrorException);
            throw jiraManagerException;
        }

        return response.Content;

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Executes a jira rest call and retuns the response if any as a business object.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">Type of the return type for deserialization.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="request">THe reste request.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private T Execute<T>(RestRequest request) where T : new()
    {
        var client = new RestClient(_jiraUrl);
        client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator(_accountId, _password);
        request.AddParameter("AccountSid", _accountId, ParameterType.UrlSegment);
        var response = client.Execute<T>(request);

        if (response.ErrorException != null)
        {
            const string message = "Error retrieving response.  Check inner details for more info.";
            var jiraManagerException = new ApplicationException(message, response.ErrorException);
            throw jiraManagerException;
        }

        return response.Data;
    }


 public void SetJiraIssue(string issueKey, JiraIssue j)
    {
        RestRequest request = new RestRequest("issue/{key}", Method.PUT);
        request.AddUrlSegment("key", issueKey);
        request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
        request.AddHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
        j.Summary = "modifiying this issue";


        request.AddBody(j);

        var response = Execute(request);
        Console.WriteLine(response);
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally found a way to make it work, it's not totally how i expected it or would of liked it to work but it's the only way i found yet. Hopefully this will be useful to someone else

```
public void SetJiraIssue(string issueKey, JiraIssue j)
    {
        RestRequest request = new RestRequest("issue/{key}", Method.PUT);
        request.AddUrlSegment("key", issueKey);
        request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;

        string jSonContent = @"{""fields"":{""summary"":""test changing summary""}}";
        request.AddParameter("application/json", jSonContent, ParameterType.RequestBody);

        var response = Execute(request);
        Console.WriteLine(response);
    }
```